# Cannot run multiple SparkContexts Pyspark filter() application of filtering stopwords using isin()

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

For this PySpark I am looking for ideas and to verify the logic usage of 'filter'.

Looking for advise on word chucks for filtering stopwords.

My first step is to read CSV. Then use (import re) to split() into word chuncks. Then apply stopwords to filter(~storm_word_chunks.isin(stopwords)). Is the usage of filter correct for x.isin() ?

Before sqlContext.spark.createDataFrame() runs, shall we define sqlContext, I must first need something like:
sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")

Following the from ... import

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")
df = spark.read.csv("StormEvents.csv")
storm_word_chunks = sc.spark.createDataFrame(df.split()))    
stopwords = ["i", "me", "my", "myself",...]    
dfStorm_words = filter(~storm_word_chunks.isin(stopwords))
```

Now when this runs I get a ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts are once; existing SparkContexts created by GetOrCreate()...

OK so how to solve this SparkContext?

Comment: tl;dr; Are you running this in `pyspark` REPL? if so, `sc` will be already available to you.

Comment: yes, PySpark, I discovered that sc was already running so I removed the sc = SparkContext()